# Looping through Images Using For Loop(#Tkinter)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, tkinter

When i run this code i get the error.. FileNotFound. i need some help to know what wrong am i doing. (Just boosting my python skills

```
  def resizemultiple():

    extensions = ('.jpeg','.jpg','.png','.svg')
    x = filedialog.askdirectory()
    Newwidth = int(width.get())
    Newheight = int(height.get())
    for f in os.listdir(x):
        if f.endswith(extensions):
            #Opening the image
            res = Image.open(f)
            #Splitting the word content
            splitimage = f.split('\\')[-1]
            fn, fext = splitimage.split('.')
            #resizing the image
            #messagebox.askyesnocancel(title=x, message="Do you want yo Resize the images")
            Newimage = res.resize((int(Newwidth), int(Newheight)))
            #messagebox._show(title="Resized", message="The Image Is Resized to " + str(Newwidth) + ' x ' + str(Newheight)+ " Press Ok To save it")
            Newimage.save('()res'.format(fext))

   messagebox._show(title="Resized", message="The Images are saved")
```

And this is what i get

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Emt_Inc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "c:/Users/Emt_Inc/Desktop/All Desktop/Random 
Coding/RatesConveter/ImageResizer.py", line 59, in resizemultiple
res = Image.open(f)
File "C:\Users\Emt_Inc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2652, in open
fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'deo.jpg'
```

Comment: The error explains itself. There is no `deo.jpg` file in your running directory. Try to change to `res = Image.open(os.join(x,f))` I am guessing this is what you meant

Answer (score 1):

listdir does not return the file with the the whole path. (See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_listdir.htm)

You need the whole path on the front. Like

```
pth = os.path.join(x, f)
Image.open(pth)
```